# Calling executemany of mySQL.connector from python with a list of tuples created from a netcdf file using numpy transpose gives a distorted query

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, sql-insert

(Microsoft Surface Pro 7, Windows 11 Home, Python 3.10.1, MySQL 8.0.33)

The goal:

- Load a netcdf-file with sizes up too about 400MB into the SQL-Database in under 15 minutes,
- the data in the necdf is given in the form of multiple two dimensional arrays,
- items at same position within the structure of different arrays belong together,
- the data needs to be transformed from multiple two dimensional arrays into a list of rows,
- RAM usage is as limitted as is time.

relevant Dependencies:

```
import mysql.connector
import os
import netCDF4 as nc
from os.path import dirname
import sys
import time
import numbers
import numpy as np
```

The SQL scheme was created from the following query:

```
USE s5p_aer;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sources` (
    `sID` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fileHash` char(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    `fileName` varchar(150) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    `length` integer NOT NULL,
    `count` integer NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(`sID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `measurements` (
    `source` integer,
    `coordinate` POINT NOT NULL,
    `time` timestamp NOT NULL,
    `cID` bigint NOT NULL, 
    `probability_of_ice` FLOAT,
    `probability_of_water` FLOAT,
    `sea_ice_fraction` FLOAT,
    `sea_surface_temperature` FLOAT,
    `surface_temperature` FLOAT,
    `quality_level` FLOAT, 
    SPATIAL INDEX `SPATIAL` (`coordinate`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`source`) REFERENCES sources(`sID`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`time`,`cID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The query succesfully executes resulting in the correct schema within the database.

The Insert to be performed ("insertDataQuery"):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO measurements(`source`,`coordinate`,`time`,`cID`,
    `probability_of_ice`,`probability_of_water`,`sea_ice_fraction`,
    `sea_surface_temperature`,`surface_temperature`,`quality_level`)
 VALUES((SELECT sID FROM `sources`
         WHERE fileHash = %s),
point(%s,%s), from_unixtime(%s),
 FLOOR(%s * POWER(10,8)+ %s * POWER(10,16)),
     %s5,%s6,%s7,%s8,%s9,%s10)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cID = cID
```

Performing the insert manually via the MySQL Workbench with a line of data from below succeeds.

The data to be inserted is stored in a list of tuples named "dat" and result of `print(dat)` is:

```
[
('0af547118346a9ee9e2f955a9a0365ea33bf279323b430dbc86b71fe562dc6a5',  '71.453', '173.49', '1416366180', '71.453', '173.49', '-100', '-100', '96.0', '-32768.0', '-32768.0', '0'), 
('0af547118346a9ee9e2f955a9a0365ea33bf279323b430dbc86b71fe562dc6a5',  '71.457', '173.44402', '1416366180', '71.457', '173.44402', '-100', '-100', '96.0', '-32768.0', '-32768.0', '0'),  
('0af547118346a9ee9e2f955a9a0365ea33bf279323b430dbc86b71fe562dc6a5',  '71.484', '173.12201', '1416366180', '71.484', '173.12201', '-100', '-100', '96.0', '-32768.0', '-32768.0', '0'), 
('0af547118346a9ee9e2f955a9a0365ea33bf279323b430dbc86b71fe562dc6a5',  '71.48801', '173.07701', '1416366180', '71.48801', '173.07701', '-100', '-100', '96.0', '-32768.0', '-32768.0', '0')
```

]

How the data is produced:

```
ds = nc.Dataset(os.path.join(dirname(__file__),file_path),'r')
time = int(ds['/time'][0]) #single value
lats = np.ravel(ds['/lat']) #ds['/lat'] is a two dimensional list of floats, hence lats is a single dimensional list of floats
dim = len(lats)
times = [time] * (dim )
lons = np.ravel(ds['/lon'])
sources = [source] * (dim)
data = [sources[:10],lats[:10],lons[:10],times[:10],lats[:10],lons[:10]]
for it in cnfg["dataScheme"]:
    data.append((np.ravel(ds[it["name"]]))[:10])
ds.close()
 #here the variable "dat" to be inserted is created
```

The origin of all evil:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, database=databaseName)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.executemany(insertDataQuery, dat)
db.commit()
cursor.close() 
db.close()
```

The big, fat, ugly error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 611, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5,'-100'6,'96.0'7,'-32768.0'8,'-32768.0'9,'0'10),((SELECT sID FROM `sources` WHE' at line 1
```

Observe that the Query seems somehow distorted.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong here?

The above queries are already verified by executing them via the MySQL Workbench.

In a previous version I created the list of tuples without NumPys transpose and ravel by itering through the two dimensional arrays in nested loops. This worked but was insufficiently performant.
(It took longer than 2 hours for the large files)

Assuming, that NumPys data types are causing the troubles, in the above script I use the .item() to extract the standard types. Previously I had: `dat = [tuple(l) for l in np.transpose(data)]`

I also tried the INSERT without IGNORE, but this did not change anything.

I suspect that some unwanted side-effects may be occuring between the sql connector and numpy but do not know, how to hunt down these bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: spurious query:

The insert-query should be:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO measurements(`source`,`coordinate`,`time`,`cID`,`probability_of_ice`,`probability_of_water`,`sea_ice_fraction`,`sea_surface_temperature`,`surface_temperature`,`quality_level`) VALUES ((SELECT sID FROM `sources` WHERE fileHash = %s), point(%s,%s), from_unixtime(%s), FLOOR(%s * 1E8+ %s * 1E16), %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cID = cID
```

That is, the last 6 placeholders "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" have been wrong: "%s5,%s6,%s7,%s8,%s9,%s10"

(finding such trivial things always takes the longest :-/ )

Thanks for the help, despite that!

Answer (score 0):

The query looks like

```
INSERT ...
    VALUES (  ( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ) , ... )
    ON ...
```

I would expect it to look like

```
INSERT ...
    ( SELECT ... , ... FROM ... WHERE ... )
    ON ...
```

(They are perhaps equivalent.)  That is, move all the values into the `SELECT` part, before the `FROM`.  Note the change in parens.

May I suggest `1E8` instead of `POWER(10,8)`.

Comment: Modified it to:

INSERT IGNORE INTO measurements(`source`,`coordinate`,`time`,`cID`,`probability_of_ice`,`probability_of_water`,`sea_ice_fraction`,`sea_surface_temperature`,`surface_temperature`,`quality_level`) (SELECT sID FROM `sources` WHERE fileHash = %s, point(%s,%s), from_unixtime(%s), FLOOR(%s * 1E8+ %s * 1E16), %s5,%s6,%s7,%s8,%s9,%s10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cID = cID

results in

"You have an error in your SQL syntax;(...)  near ', point('71.453','173.49'), from_unixtime('1416366180'), FLOOR('71.453' * 1E8+ '' at line 1"

Compactifying to scientific notationis good, thanks!

Comment: Study the syntax.  Search this forum for "upsert" or "IODKU" or "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" for more examples